# Pick up sticks Game

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Hi have made the game Pick up sticks and it works ok except for 2 parts. I want the program to display a message for an invalid input such as" can only enter numbers 1 or 2". Also I have tried to make it where at the end you choose whether or not to continue but it doesnt seem to work.Can someone help me with these parts of code?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sticks {

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(System.in));

 int numSticks = 21;
 System.out.println("Would You Like to go first? (Yes/No)");
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 String goFirst = input.nextLine();
 Scanner take = new Scanner (System.in);
 int numToTake = 0;
 int score = 0;
 int input1;
 int B = 1;



 while (numSticks > 0) {

   if (goFirst.equals("Yes") || goFirst.equals("yes")) {
     System.out.println("There are " + numSticks + " sticks ");
     System.out.println("How many sticks do you want to take (1 or 2)");
     numToTake = take.nextInt();

     if (numToTake > 2) {
       numToTake = 2;

     }

     else if (numToTake < 1) {
       numToTake = 1;
     }
     numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

     if (numSticks <= 0) {
       System.out.println("You lose");
       System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
     }
     else {

       if((numSticks - 2) % 3 == 0 || numSticks - 2 == 0) {
         numToTake = 1;
       }
       else {
         numToTake = 2;
       }
       System.out.println("Computer takes " + numToTake + " sticks " );
       numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

       if (numSticks <= 0) {
         System.out.println(" You win ");
         score++;
         System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
       }
     }

  }
  else {
         if((numSticks - 2) % 3 == 0 || numSticks - 2 == 0) {
         numToTake = 1;
       }
       else {
         numToTake = 2;
       }
       System.out.println("Computer takes" + numToTake + " sticks " );
       numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

       if (numSticks <= 0) {
         System.out.println("You win");
         score++;
         System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("There are " + numSticks + " sticks ");
           System.out.println("How many sticks do you want to take (1 or 2)");
           numToTake = take.nextInt();

           if (numToTake > 2) {
               numToTake = 2;
           }
           else if (numToTake < 1){
               numToTake = 1;
           }
           numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

           if(numSticks <= 0){
               System.out.println("You win");
               score++;
               System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
           }


            }
       int Y=5, N=10;
       System.out.println("Your score is "+ score);
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? Press(5) For Yes/(10) For No");
       input1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       if(input1==Y){
         B=1;   
         System.out.println("There are 21 sticks How many sticks do you want to take (1 or 2)");
       }
       else if(input1==N)
       {System.exit(0);
        System.out.println("Have A Good Day!");
           }
  }
 }
```

}
 }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Comment: Please also change your code example to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The minimal, complete and verifiable example @TimothyTruckle suggests, don't just create it because it will enable us to help you. Do it even more because it will help you understand and likely even solve your own problems.

Comment: It would help to structure your program with methods.  Have a method such as `playOneGame` and then have a method like `playGames` which calls `playOneGame` and the asks the user to continue or not and loops as needed.  As for checking `numToTake` you could put your current validation into a helper method which takes `numToTake` as an arg, validates, prints the message if needed, and returns the updated value.